# Perfect square palindromic numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, palindrome

A palindromic number is one which when expressed in base $10$ with no leading zeros, reads the same left to right and right to left.  For example, $44944$ is a (base 10) palindrome.

I can find quite a few palindromes which are also perfect squares; indeed there are an infinite set of them of the form $1,121,10201,1002001, \ldots$.  In each of these cases, however, the square root of the palindrome is itself a palindrome.

I would like to know about palindromes which are the square of non-palindromes:

- Are there any perfect square palindromes whose square roots are not palindromic?
- Is there an infinite set of perfect square palindromes whose square roots are not palindromic?
- Are the answers to these questions different in other bases?

Comment: I'm not sure there are any palindromic squares that are not of the form $(10^n + 1)^m$  Maybe you should answer that first.

Comment: $$212^2 = 44944$$

Comment: $307^2=94249$ is an example.

Comment: @Peter: Bingo on question (a).  Can't believe I missed that one.

Comment: An online search shows that the [largest known example](http://www.worldofnumbers.com/square.htm) is $(1,373,512,530,649,258,635,292,477,609)^2=1,886,536,671,850,530,641,991,373,196,913,731,991,460,350,581,766,356,881$

Comment: The relevant OEIS sequences are [A002778](http://oeis.org/A002778) for the square root and [A002779](http://oeis.org/A002779) for the squares.

Comment: And I cannot believe that I missed $26^2=676$

Comment: It seems that the answer to the second question is yes, but a proof seems to be difficult.

Comment: @lulu OEIS contains a lot of stuff!

Comment: @Peter  It's addictive.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer!

The examples below a million are :

```
26 676
264 69696
307 94249
836 698896
2285 5221225
2636 6948496
22865 522808225
24846 617323716
30693 942060249
798644 637832238736
```